# AJAX, JQuery, Parse - which one will get me my array?

Tags: ajax, rest

In my codeacademy and codeschool lessons, I've been fetching data from google rss and simulated twitter feeds.

My newest exercise, however, involves fetching an array of text data from a REST API.

When I try

```
$.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=-createdAt', function(x){$('.messages').append('<li>'+x.responseText+'</li>');});
```

I get

[image]

which has the text and username I need. Sort of...

but when I try to **alert** or **console.log** either ***x.responseText** or **x.responseText.results** I obviously get **undefined** instead of an array.

What am I missing?
Study more AJAX and I'll find a technique?
Or do I have to send special instructions to the parse server using some commands found [here](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using XMLHttpRequest directly, you are using jQuery and it will read the `responseText` and handle it for you.

Just use `x` (or, rather, `x.results`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm a step closer. I got [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], so it's up to plain old javascript to open these objects and extract the text?

Comment: Yes, you can see the properties of those objects in your screenshot.

Comment: But seeing that these objects are not part of an array, is it still possible to iterate through them (to get their properties) with plain javascript? I've only been practicing AJAX data dumps for a day now...

Comment: They *are* items in an array.

Comment: or maybe they ARE an array and they're just displaying on my browser as seperate objects... - got it - thx